# How do I use neural network to predict variables in linear equations?

Tags: neural-network

I am going to calibrate two monitors. Two variables "Brightness" and "Contrast" can be adjusted to obtain the monitor's color properties (Its pixel values).

First, I use some calibration equipment to measure the first monitor's color space property. Then, I use a regression method to obtain a straight line representing the gray level change of that panel. Hence, I find the slope of that line representing the contrast and the y-intercept representing the brightness correlated to that monitor.

My question is how to apply my prior knowledge to adjust another monitor's brightness and contrast as same as my first monitor?

Assume that I also use calibration equipment to measure the second monitor's color property.

Can I use neural network to obtain the true value of contrast and brightness of another monitor?